# Positional report on Sybase

Tags: report, sybase, space, digits

i need to create a syabase report where i need to consider for each field the digits and the space between each sigle fields. Example considering TABA:

```
OUTPUT
NAME             SURNAME           TELEPHONE
ROBERT           ROSSI             0123456789
```

So between the columns NAME and SURNAME we have 20 digit of spaces. And between SURNAME and TELEPHONE we have 35 digits of spaces.

There is a way to do this on sybase?
Thank you

Comment: I only count 13 and 11 spaces between NAME/SURNAME and SURNAME/TELEPHONE, respectively; spacing between columns is typically left up to the client/application (eg, `isql` will space out columns to allow for a single empty space between columns; if the intent is to have a query generate a single line of text with fixed-widths then use use a combination of `convert(char(xx)...)` and/or `+space(yy)+` (between columns) ... though you'll also need to keep in mind the `max()` width of your data when determining overall column width

Comment: You can also use sp_autoformat which might be just what you need - http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1570/html/sprocs/BABHCBIG.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot, i solved the problem!